# Unable to solve ngOnit is missing

Tags: angular

Unable to solve this error tried various solutions for the same.
Getting error in ngonit is missing in type 'homeController'
Any help will be appreciated

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation  } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers} from '@angular/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
   templateUrl: './home.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

 constructor(private http: Http) { }

Users = [];
FetchData = Function() {
this.http.get("http://localhost:5555/users").subscribe(
  (res: Response) => {
    this.users = res.json();
  }
)
}

ngOnInit() {
this.FetchData();   
}

}
```

Comment: mark as answer if the answer helped

Answer (score 1):

Change your function as,

```
FetchData() {
this.http.get("http://localhost:5555/users").subscribe(
  (res: Response) => {
    this.users = res.json();
  }
)
}
```